# Reading a text file with a Scanner in Java - Token's return character

Tags: java, file-io, io, text-files

I'm triying to read the text file below with a [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) in a simple Java Program.

```
0001;GUAJARA-MIRIM;RO
0002;ALTO ALEGRE DOS PARECIS;RO
0003;PORTO VELHO;RO
```

I read the text file using the code below:

```
scanner = new Scanner(filerader).useDelimiter("\\;|\\n");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int id= scanner.nextInt();
    String name = scanner.next();
    String code = scanner.next();

    System.out.printf(".%s.%s.%d.\n", name, code, id);
}
```

The results are:

```
.GUAJARA-MIRIM.RO.1
.
.ALTO ALEGRE DOS PARECIS.RO.2
.
.PORTO VELHO.RO.3
.
```

But the result of the third token of each line has an incovenient '\r' caracther at the end (ANSI code 13). I have no idea why (I used the '.' character on the formatting string to to make it clear where the '\r' is).

So,

1. Why there's a '\r' at the end of the third token?
2. How to bypass it.

It is very simple to use an workaround like `code.substring(0, 2)`, but instead I want to understand why there's a '\r' character there.

Comment: Hi! How can I do it? I see my rate is 0% but I don't known how to change it.

Comment: Just click one of the checkmarks next to an answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some file systems(specially Windows), `\r\n` is used a **new line character**. You are using `\n` only a delimiter so `\r` remain out. Add `\r` also in your delimiters.

To make your code little more robust, use `System.lineSeparator()` to get the new line characters and use the delimiters accordingly.

Comment: I used the pattern "\\;|\\r\\n" and it worked fine!
Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @RafaelBorja Good to know. Please accept the answer you like.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Windows file, which uses `\r\n` as line delimiters (aka Carriage Return Line Feed). Unix uses only `\n` (Line Feed).

To fix this, add `\r` to your scanner delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it happens is already given, Other way to avoid this is to use `scanner.nextLine()` and then split by ; .